# How to align tab content kept in bootstrap container class with full-width nav-tabs li items

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have come through an issue where I have my tab-content kept in bootstrap container class and I want full-width nav-tabs with its labels aligned to left side . But what I wanted to align the nav-tabs first li tab item with the tab-content.Please have a look at the example created by me in codepen :

Click [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGvava) to access the CodePen.

```css
body{padding-top:5px;}
.navTabsParent{}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a{
background-color: #D7E1EA;
border: 0px solid #DDD;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a{
  border-radius:0 !important;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a{color:#182E79;font-weight:bold;}
.tabOneLink,.tabTwoLink{text-align:left !important;}

.main-content-body{background-color: #D7E1EA;}
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid navTabsParent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified ">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" class="tabOneLink" href="#tab1"><p>Tab One</p></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="tabTwoLink" href="#tab2">
      <p>Tab Two</p></a></li>
  </ul>
      <div class="main-content-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
       <h2>Tab 1:</h2>
         <h4>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</h4>
              </div> <!--End of #tab1 -->
            <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in">
       <h2>Tab 2:</h2>
         <h4>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</h4>
              </div> <!--End of #tab2 -->

              
              </div> <!--End of .tab-content -->
              </div> <!--End of .col-12 -->
          </div> <!--end .row --> 
        </div> <!--end .container -->
      </div> <!--Main Content body -->
    </div> <!--End of .col-12 -->
  </div> <!--End of .row -->
</div> <!--End of .container-fluid -->
```

[View that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlzOb.png)

Comment: No link to your codepen

Comment: Guys plese refer the link .i forgot to add link .http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGvava

Comment: @jbg http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGvava

Comment: you can edit your question and put it in there

Answer (score 0):

I added `col-lg-6` to the class attribute of the div that has `id="tab1"` and that stuff now fits under the "tab one" element.  Next, I removed `class="tab-content"` from the div directly above tab1 and the tab2 info fits under the "tab two".

Additionally, do not use more than one `col-XX-##` (such as `col-lg-6`) per div, as it doesn't make any sense to do that.  Do yourself a favor and review how the grid system in bootstrap works.

[My revision of your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVLzxR)

Comment: Hi Tim .Thanks for the help . can you please edit my code and share the codepen with the updated one . will be a great help. thanks

Comment: Tim I guess you dint understood the context of my questions , actually what I wanted is , the nav-tabs li item one that is TabOne should align with the tab content items .